# Why my daily reputation capped at 199 points?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Today I received the maximum amount of points possible on StackOverflow - **199** (?).

I answered questions and got 21 up votes 1 down vote and down-voted one answer.

I know it sounds a bit picky but why didn't I receive 200 points (and a badge)?

Comment: The same thing happened to me.  It is a conspiracy.  The extra points are dropped off and funneled into Jon Skeet's reputation instead.

Comment: Congrats on hitting the rep cap!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You only recieved 199 points because you downvoted once (bringing your rep down 1 point).

You have still hit the cap and you'll recieve your `Mortarboard` badge in a few hours.