# Is there a 197 rep cap per day?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why my daily reputation capped at 199 points?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32569/why-my-daily-reputation-capped-at-199-points)

I have selected 'today' in my recent activity view. As you can see from the screenshot, i am getting no more points for upvotes, thought i only earned 197 rep points today.

[rep points http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/9335/reps.jpg](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/9335/reps.jpg)

what am i doing wrong here?

edit:

to make it a bit more interesting: (not) more points...

[rep2 http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/9335/reps.jpg](http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/9335/reps.jpg)

Comment: Duplicated a billion times. Just do a quick search for reputation cap to find out more than you've ever wanted to know about its silliness.

Comment: Go find and read the duplicates. The key point is that the rep cap is sensitive the the order things happen in. Extra credit if you can deduce *why* it is done that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Unsliced pointed out, there is a 200 rep cap per day.

However, if you downvoted anyone today, you would lower the rep cap (1 per day)

Furthermore, it is possible that you actually got more than 200 rep today and the recent activity page is still cached. Eventually it will update to say that you got 200 rep.

Make sure you click on 'today', because clicking on the envelop brings you to a custom recent activity page that shows you stuff since you last visited.

Comment: Why answer duplicates? why? why??

Comment: @downvoter, even dupes need good answers

Comment: @lance, I disagree, answers should be on the root question, that's what the link is there for

Answer (score -2):

The limit is 200, another upvote would take you over that limit.

Comment: This is not correct. Other factors like downvotes aside, you would still get the partial reputation for the upvote that still fits in the rep cap window.

Comment: you can see that 56s ago i received an upvote but no points for it.