# I got two upvote on an answer but the reputation got only 3

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I got two upvote on an answer for following question but the reputation got only 3.

[INSERT statement that checks if an equivalent row already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637286/insert-statement-that-checks-if-an-equivalent-row-already-exists/10637335#10637335)

For one upvote, I got +3 and none for another vote.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit curious why you even got the 3, as that would put you at 203 for the day.

Comment: @animuson Yes that's weird.

Comment: @animuson Off the top of my head, maybe downvotes he cast?

Comment: @waiwai933: Those aren't supposed to be counted towards the daily limit. [See this question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32569)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hit the rep cap for the day.

Comment: then how come +3 ? what is 3 reputation means ?

Comment: what you mean by rep cap?

Comment: @Romil You can earn up to 200 reputation daily from upvotes and suggested edits (excluding rep from having your answer accepted)

Comment: @yannis, it means if I got more than 200 reputation from upvotes then what will happen for the reputation of further upvotes.

Comment: @Romil It's a daily limit, you can only earn 200 reputation per UTC day. Every upvote after that doesn't earn you reputation, you can still earn badges though.